# Unity: Fast-Forward Type Writer Effect upon Keypress

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, ienumerator

For the cutscenes of a 2D platformer game, I wrote a script that shows the text like it's written by a typewriter. Since the text can be very long, I want to implement an option for the user to fast-forward/skip the animation and show the full text upon a keypress. This is what I have right now:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TypeWriter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float delay = 0.05f;
    public string fullText;
    private string currentText = "";

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ShowText());
    }

    IEnumerator ShowText()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fullText.Length + 1; i++)
        {
            currentText = fullText.Substring(0, i);
            this.GetComponent<Text>().text = currentText;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me please? I'm new to unity as well as C#.

Comment: You can add the ScrollBar UI component to display long text.

Comment: Just put a flag in the coroutine that doesn't yield wait when the flag is set. If that flag is set the whole loop will run out and there will be no yield therefore no more waiting. Trigger the flag on keypress.

Comment: @Charleh Thanks for your reply! What do you mean by flag? Can you maybe show it in code? I have no experience with Unity or C#, sorry!

Comment: A Boolean value basically. True/false. If you set it to true skip the yield. If you are new to programming I'd suggest doing a beginner course, you'll learn stuff faster that way.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a flag should do the trick:

```
    bool skip = false;

    IEnumerator ShowText()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fullText.Length + 1; i++)
        {
            currentText = fullText.Substring(0, i);
            this.GetComponent<Text>().text = currentText;
            if (!skip)
              yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        }
    }
```

Just set `skip` to `true` at some point and it will cause the loop to not yield which will result in the loop full completing (a minor optimisation would be to just not loop when the skip flag is set and just fill the text with the remaining letters instead, but I doubt you will have performance issues even with the loop as it's so simple).

You can set the flag to true based on receiving a keypress/some input.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Start()
{
    textRef = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
    fullText = textRef.text;
    GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = "";
    if (typeOnStart)
        StartCoroutine(ShowText(typingDelay));
}
public void StartTyping(float delay)
{
    StartCoroutine(ShowText(typingDelay));
}
IEnumerator ShowText(float delay)
{
    // float time = Time.deltaTime;
    for (int i = 0; i <= fullText.Length; i++)
    {
        // Debug.Log("Typing");
        currentText = fullText.Substring(0, i);
        textRef.text = currentText;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(typingDelay);
    }
    // float time2 = Time.deltaTime;
    // Debug.Log("Total Time Taken  : " + (time2 - time));
}
```

}